# How to get data from database to arraylist and show them

Tags: java, android, database, arraylist

I am trying to get data from database to `arraylist` and then show them. Unfortunately I get this

> error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError

thrown while trying to throw an exception; no stack trace available. I am using own class for Object, which are store in database.

MainActivity code:

```
narodyList = db.getVsechnyNarody(); 
String k = narodyList.get(1).toString();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Záznam" + k,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

DatabaseHandler.java:

```
 public List<Narody> getVsechnyNarody(){
        List<Narody> narodyList = new ArrayList<Narody>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NARODY;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Narody narod = new Narody();
                narod.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                narod.setNazevNaroda(cursor.getString(1));
                narodyList.add(narod);
            } while (cursor.moveToFirst());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return narodyList;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is probably on line 13.

This line keeps you stuck in infinite loop (you are moving to first row every time the loop is executed):

```
} while (cursor.moveToFirst());
```

Replace it with this line:

```
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
```

I hope this helped